# I want to add inputted numbers into an array, then add them together for now but I keep getting undefined array ? javascript html

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code and I am trying to get it to be put into an array and added together but keeps becoming an undefined array.

```
  var myHTML = '';
  let numa = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < input; i++) {
    myHTML += '<span class="test">Mark #' + (i + 1) + ' Name: ' + '</span>  <input type="text" id="markname" <br/> <span class="markn">Mark: ' 
        + '</span>  <input type="text" class="marknum"  <br/><br/>'
    ;

    wrapper.innerHTML = myHTML
    var newinput = document.getElementsByClassName('marknum').value;
    numa.push(newinput);
    console.log(numa);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is that all of the code? It doesn't seem to really work at all in the fashion that you have posted.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` will return a list of elements, so you can't just grab a value like that.

Answer (score 1):

1. Everything other than the code that adds new HTML to the variable should be outside the loop.
2. `getElementsByClassName` returns a live nodelist which is an [*array-like* list of elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName). Even if there's only one element you can't grab the value like that.
3. It's not clear how you intend to check when the values have been changed, so in this example I'm going to use a button that calls a function to calculate the sum of the values in the inputs.

```js
// Cache your elements, and add an event listener to
// the button
const wrapper = document.querySelector('#wrapper');
const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

let myHTML = '';

// Create your HTML
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  myHTML += `<label>Mark</label><input type="text" /><br />`;
}

wrapper.innerHTML = myHTML;

function handleClick() {

  // Grab all the inputs in the `wrapper` container
  const inputs = wrapper.querySelectorAll('input');

  // `querySelectorAll` also returns an array-like list
  // so we need to create an array from it before we
  // can use array methods on it like: `reduce`
  // Basically `reduce` takes an initial value, and then iterates
  // over the array adding to that value
  // and then passing that value back into the callback.
  // Here: we're coercing the
  // input value (a string) to a number, and then summing it with
  // the sum from the previous iteration
  const numa = Array.from(inputs).reduce((acc, input) => {
    return acc + Number(input.value);
  }, 0);

  console.log(numa);

}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
<button>Calculate</button>
```

Additional documentation

- [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: Thank you @Andy this works but everytime I click submit it multiplies the labels that comes up is there any way to work through that?